# RmD files corrupted in one git subdirectory

Tags: r, git, github, r-markdown

In opening some R Markdown Files (RmD) that I last worked on ~8 months ago, all the files of that type in one git subdirectory seem [corrupted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mkVo.png). It's the same problem whether I try to open in R Studio or TextEdit, and across multiple computers (all Mac though). The problem does not affect other RmD files in other subdirectories, or other file types in the same subdirectory. I've tried all the "Reopen with encoding" options in R Studio, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970101/rstudio-r-file-corruption) thread, but it doesn't seem to address my problem. Any ideas on how I might be able to open these files to edit them, and how can I avoid this kind of problem in the future?

Comment: If you have an uncorrupted version of the repository you should be able to revert changes.  If your local copy of the repository is corrupted, you may be able to restore from a remote copy, or a backup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How can I figure out when the corruption occurred? I have made many changes to other files in the repo since I last tried to work with these files.

Comment: You should be able to see the revision history of those files.  What tool are you using for git (Github's web page, command line git, or ?)

Comment: SourceTree. The files are also on Github, and I've browed the revision history there.

Comment: If it is a public repository: can you provide a link? In general, [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) is a good tool to find the problematic commit.