# How to restore my R commands when receiving the error Magic number

Tags: r, rstudio, corruption

I am begging for help!! I have been training myself in R for over 2 months and ALL my code and explanations I wrote for my own understanding is in one file that I have saved last this afternoon and I never had troubles opening it up until now. This is the error code I receive:

> Error in load("D:/AIHR Training/R Training.R") :
> bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
> truncating string with embedded nuls
> 2: file ‘R Training.R’ has magic number ''
> Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

Please note I am a beginner so I have no idea what to do but I am desperate to receive my list of commands back as I have invested such a long time in this file.

I have also tried read.csv and source() instead of load() as read in a different conversation on this forum but it didn't help me. Nothing works

Furthermore, when I try to drag my saved file in the RStudio, all I can see where I used to have my huge list of commands and explanation only 1 row with dots on a red background (please note the colours of my RStudio are inverted to black so it might look different for other users.

I have also tried to see if I can restore a previous version of the file but there aren't any as I assume I overwrote the previous one today, last time I saved my commands with the Ctrl + S keys.

My commands are not in the History either.

I don't know what else to try, but I am DESPERATE as the training is quite complicated to me so I wrote loads of explanations for myself along the way...

PLEASE tell me there's a way to restore my commands ...

Comment: Have you tried opening the file with a simple text editor like Notepad++ ?

Comment: Hi Allan,i have tried with my basic Notepad and it looks empty when I open it. Blank

Comment: @Dia.D - if your file is really blank in notepad, then it is truly empty - there is no data there to load. What is the filesize?

Comment: The size is 55KB. Is that small?...

Comment: `load` is _not_ the command to open an R script, it is for saved data. You are not loading the file correctly. Go to "file", then "open file", then open the R file.

Comment: No, that's not small, maybe you have 55KB of null characters. `save` version 2 files should start with `"RDA2"`, that's the magic number.

Comment: What is your version of R?

Comment: @Axeman I have tried that too. That's when I get the red dotted line

Comment: @RuiBarradas R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24) -- "Arbor Day"

Comment: @Dia.D Try opening the file in Notepad++ as Allan suggested. If the filesize is 55kb, you definitely have *some* data in there - it should not be blank. Notepad++ would show NUL characters if that's what's in there.

Comment: @Klaycon I am trying to download and install it now and I'll get back to you as soon as I manage

Comment: @Klaycon just opened it with Notepad++ and all I can see is NUL NUL NUL...
Please tell me there is still something, ANYTHING I can do to restore!! Even if it's a version from a previous day...

Comment: @Dia.D I hate to be the one to break the bad news...

Comment: @Dia.D I'm sorry. Maybe the answers here might help: [RStudio R File Corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970101/rstudio-r-file-corruption)

Comment: @AllanCameron oh gosh...!!! What did I even do??? There's NOTHING that I've done different today from all the other times for the past 2 months....

Comment: Even if the file is gone, most things are googlable. You'll do just fine, I'm sure.