# Is that possible to retrieve shiny app source .R files from shinyapp.io?

Tags: r, shinyapps, corruption, recovery

This is related to corrupted files recovery ([RStudio R File Corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970101/rstudio-r-file-corruption))

Is that possible to see (retrieve) source .R and .Rmd files of the Shiny App that was deployed shinyapp.io?

Lets say - you have just successfully  uploaded/deployed your Shiny app to shinyapp.io and then your shiny app code got corrupted on your local machine. Can you recover it from deployed codes?

Comment: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/204536588-Downloading-your-application-from-shinyapps-io

Comment: This strikes me as a question for Posit, not for this community.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, if you deployed your code to shinyapps, you are lucky, all your codes are there!
See this article: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/204536588-Downloading-your-application-from-shinyapps-io