# RStudio failure results in all my .R scripts corrupted? help )-:

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio, data-corruption

today I encountered an issue with RStudio where it crashed after I opened it. Subsequently, I noticed that several of my previously saved .R script files on my computer have been affected. While I can still see these .R files in their original locations, they now appear to be either completely empty (0 KB in size) or contain only the initial few lines of code. This problem occurs whether I try to open the files in RStudio, R, or even Notepad. I'm seeking assistance in understanding the potential cause behind this issue and any possible solutions to recover or fix these files. I tried to recover the files with data recovery tools, but it doesn't work. Your insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you make backups of the files anywhere? If the files are 0 bytes now, there's nothing really to restore. What OS is this? And What RStudio version are you using? You are probably better off asking for help at the RStudio community support site: https://community.rstudio.com/ or filing a bug report in their github issues: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Comment: Possibly related: https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-code-file-is-becoming-0-kb-after-saving/138585/4. Suggestions for recovery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970101/rstudio-r-file-corruption